# Swift 4 "Extra argument in call" Rxswift

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I updated from Swift 3 to 4, and i am using RxSwift, When updated i came across an error "Extra argument in call" as it expects now of type element. I tried creating tuple of (response, data) but still gives me an error as shown.

```
     public static func deleteCrush(receiver: String, receiver_type: ProviderType) -> Observable<(HTTPURLResponse, NSArray)> {
    /*
     Delete crush identified by `id`

   */

    let parameters: Parameters = [
        "receiver": receiver,
        "receiver_type": receiver_type.rawValue
    ]

    print("deleteCrush paramreters: \(parameters)")

    return Observable.create({ (observer) -> Disposable in
        Alamofire.request(Router.deleteCrush(parameters: parameters))
            .rx
            .responseJSON()
            .debug()
            .subscribe(onNext: { (response, json) in
                print("deleteCrush response code: ", response.statusCode)
                if let data = json as? NSArray {
                    observer.on(.next(response, data))
                    observer.on(.completed)
                }
            }, onError: { (error) in
                print("deleteCrush error: ", error)
                observer.on(.error(error))
            }, onCompleted: nil, onDisposed: nil)
    })
}
```

**Error:** Extra argument in call.
**After trying to fix:**

```
     var tuple = (response, json)
                 if let data = json as? NSArray {
                    observer.on(.next(tuple))
                    observer.on(.completed)
                }
```

**Error:**

> Event<(HTTPURLResponse, NSDictionary)>' produces result of type 'Event', but context expects 'Event<(HTTPURLResponse, NSDictionary)>

Comment: Please post code and errors as text, not as image.

Comment: Sure, right away!

Comment: How does your function definition look which wraps this Observable

Comment: @Sandeep I updated the code

Comment: Your return type is an observer specified with a tuple. Wrap the parameters you are passing to `.next` with parenthesis, like `.next((response, data))`

Comment: @OscarVGG gives me another error  'Closure tuple parameter does not support destructuring'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just seems like you are not passing correct data type to your events.

Either simply wrap your tuple properly,

```
observer.on(.next((response, data)))
```

Or then use proper tuple type for your Element type,

```
if let data = json as? NSArray {
   var tuple = (response, data)

   observer.on(.next(tuple))
   observer.on(.completed)
 }
```

*Note that you are setting tuple as `tuple = (response, json)`* which is not correct according to your method return type.

Answer (score 0):

Swift is probably having a hard time figuring out the type of the of the data you are sending in `.next`. Sometimes this happens and the compiler provides a completely useless error message

Check your function definition. Specifically the return type. The observer you're returning may not be of the same type you are sending to your observers.

Comment: It was fine, until i converted to Swift 4, and the call now expects 1 object of type Element, and does not accept tuples anymore.