# Extra argument In Call When Using Searchbar

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I am getting the error 'Extra Argument in Call' when I am trying to implement a search bar into my app.

I have read other questions that include:

[Swift - Extra Argument in call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795035/swift-extra-argument-in-call)

[Swift 4 “Extra argument in call” Rxswift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49923610/swift-4-extra-argument-in-call-rxswift)

And others but have come up with no success.

Here is my code:

```
extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    todoItems = todoItems.filter("title CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchBar.text!).sorted(byKeyPath: "dateCreated", ascending: true) // Getting Error on this line

    tableView.reloadData()

}


func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchBar.text?.count == 0 {
        loadItems()

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks to anyone who helps!

Comment: What is the type of `todoItems`? Is it `Results<T>` from Realm database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up `NSPredicate` and `filter` syntax as well as `NSSortDescriptor` and `sorted` syntax. This cannot work.

Assuming `todoItems` is an array of a custom struct or class the native Swift way is

```
todoItems = todoItems.filter{ $0.title.range(of: searchBar.text!, options: [.caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive]) != nil}
                     .sorted{ $0.dateCreated < $1.dateCreated}
```

Note: Consider that you are going to overwrite the array containing all items with the filtered array...